# Merging selected columns from multiple pandas dataframe by comparing the values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have **df1** as follows:

```
id
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

I have **df2** as:

```
id1 name1 val1
1   abbb1  10
2   abbb2  20
3   abbb3  30
4   abbb4  40
7   abbb7  70
```

I have **df3** as:

```
id2 name2 val2
1   abbb1  90
2   abbb2  20
5   abbb5  50
6   abbb6  60
```

So, I want to pick values from **df2** and **df3**, add it to df1 by matching the ids. So, df1 should look as follows:

```
id  val1 val2
1   10   90
2   20   20
3   30   0
4   40   0
5   0    40
6   0    60
7   70   0
```

All I reached was till this line of code, and I got stuck:

```
df1 = df1.merge(df2, df3, on=['id'])
```

Please note that:

- I don't want to have name1 and name2 in the expected output.
- If val1 or val2 does not exists (after comparing), I want the cell to
  contain 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think here is better use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html).

Also is necessary unique values of `id1` and `id2` in `df2` and `df3`.

```
df1['val1'] = df1['id'].map(df2.set_index('id1')['val1']).fillna(0).astype(int)
df1['val2'] = df1['id'].map(df3.set_index('id2')['val2']).fillna(0).astype(int)
print (df1)
   id  val1  val2
0   1    10    90
1   2    20    20
2   3    30     0
3   4    40     0
4   5     0    50
5   6     0    60
6   7    70     0
```

Alternative:

```
a = df1['id'].map(df2.set_index('id1')['val1']).fillna(0).astype(int)
b = df1['id'].map(df3.set_index('id2')['val2']).fillna(0).astype(int)
df1 = df1.assign(val1=a, val2=b)
print (df1)
   id  val1  val2
0   1    10    90
1   2    20    20
2   3    30     0
3   4    40     0
4   5     0    50
5   6     0    60
6   7    70     0
```

Solution with [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html):

```
df1 = df1.merge(pd.merge(df2.rename(columns={'id1':'id'}), 
                         df3.rename(columns={'id2':'id'}), on='id', how='outer')
                [['id','val1','val2']].fillna(0).astype(int), how='left')
print (df1)
   id  val1  val2
0   1    10    90
1   2    20    20
2   3    30     0
3   4    40     0
4   5     0    50
5   6     0    60
6   7    70     0
```

Comment: map was a smart idea. Because merge statement started getting complicated with my real query. Thanks!